# Do I need to close stream if I didn't correctly open it?

Tags: ios, cfreadstream

Do I need to close stream if I didn't correctly open it?

```
if (!CFReadStreamOpen(stream))
    {
        //Do I need to add
       //CFReadStreamClose(stream)
        CFRelease(stream);
        stream = nil;
    }
```